# Не собирается проект в android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Прошу, помогите. Пару дней назад скачал android studio 4.0 и создал новый проект (empty activity). Проект не собирается, пишет: "DEM_CHAT_APPP (это название проекта) failed at (здесь дата и время)". В чем дело и что с этим делать? Если что, проект полностью пустой (empty activity). [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а у вас интернет подключен? посмотрите там event log есть ошибка там должна быть

Comment: Вангую что у Вас windows, поэтому запустите файл `gradlew.bat` из консоли с аргументом `build`. должна появиться ошибка внятная, по которой уже можно убдет чтото искать

Comment: Ошибка: Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap. Попробовал в Java Runtime Environment Settings поменять параметр runtime parametrs на -XX:MaxHeapSize=2G, но все равно не помогло, таже самая ошибка.

Comment: Студия вроде предлагает решения в один клик в подобных случаях - вы вывод во вкладке `Build` хорошо посмотрели?. Попробуйте вписать строку `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2g` в файл `gradle.properties` (должен быть в корне проекта - если его нет создайте). https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:configuring_jvm_memory . А вообще-то на скрине у вас ошибка соединения с сервером. Проверьте не включен ли оффлайн режим для gradle, есть ли у вас интернет и настройте прокси, если используется